# How to export cplex' solution?

Tags: file-io, io, stdout, cplex

I have a file `quadratic_obj.lp` with the following content:

```
Minimize
obj: a + b + [ a^2 + 4 a * b + 7 b^2 ]/2
Subject To
c1: a + b >= 10
End
```

In an interactive cplex session, I read in the file using `read`, I optimize using `optimize`. Then I can display the solution using

```
display solution variables -
```

which gives me

```
Variable Name           Solution Value
a                            10.000000
b                             0.000000
```

Is there a way to pipeline this output? So in an ideal world there would be something like:

```
display solution variables - -> myoutput.csv
```

I used `write` but the file type options there are not what I look for. E.g. `sol` is returned as an `xml` which I would have to parse again.

Is there a way to just export the variables and their values to e.g. a tab- or comma-separated file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this from the interactive.  If you do something like the following, it gets you close:

```
./cplex -c "read quadratic_obj.lp" "opt" "set logfile tmp.log" "display solution variables -" "quit"
```

This will put the output into a file named tmp.log, but there is still some extra stuff in there that you'd need to post-process with a script (or something like this).  See [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/InteractiveOptimizer/topics/useCmdsFileFromOS.html) link (for version 12.6.3) for more information on this technique.

Another alternative would be to use the [API's](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/APIs/part_languages_title_synopsis.html).  Then, you have complete control over the output.  For example, using the Python API, you could do something like the following:

```
import cplex

cpx = cplex.Cplex()
cpx.read('quadratic_obj.lp')
cpx.solve()
# Check solution status here via cpx.solution.get_status()
for name, value in zip(cpx.variables.get_names(),
                       cpx.solution.get_values()):
    print name, value
```

Comment: That works well (the Python API version; did not try the other one) - thanks! I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on other answers' quality.

Comment: Support for Python 3.6 was added with CPLEX 12.8. See the detailed system requirements [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100).

Answer (score 2):

you can do that within CPLEX with OPL:

```
dvar float+ a;
dvar float+ b;

minimize a + b + ( a*a + 4 *a * b + 7 *b*b )/2;
subject to
{
c1: a + b >= 10;
}

execute
{
var f=new IloOplOutputFile("res.csv");
f.writeln(a);
f.writeln(b);
f.close();
}
```

and this will create a csv file res.csv
regards

Comment: Does not work for me, unfortunately. It either complains about the multiplication (`CPLEX Error  1607: Line 4: Expected '+' or '-', found '*'.`), if I go back to my original definition it complains about the curly brackets (`CPLEX Error  1608: Line 10: Expected '+','-' or sense, found '{'.`) and without them I get `CPLEX Error  1608: Line 10: Expected '+','-' or sense, found 'v'.`Any ideas?

Comment: You should use what I wrote in a file model.mod and then in command line do oplrun model.mod

Comment: Then I get: `Command 'oplrun' does not exist.  Type 'help' for a list of commands.`

Comment: which cplex version do you use ? which platform ?

Comment: I tried it with 12.2. and 12.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10.

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=a22e2756-ac6d-4bc8-91ca-8a3ec93498e1

Comment: This link helped. So I upvote your answer as well, thanks!